Travelling with two passports, both are valid from the same country
I have two passports, both still valid. I haven't used the newest one, though.
I will be traveling from China to Malaysia. I want to visit Malaysia for sightseeing and to visit some friends. I can get a tourist visa on arrival for 90 days as I am eligible for it. I am planning to stay for nearly a month or a bit longer. I will book a return ticket and stay with my friend. I will also have cash with me.
My question is: Can I use my old passport to get the exit stamp from the immigration authorities in China since it has the visa and entry stamp from China? Note: I am staying legally in China and I am not overstaying.
If the Chinese immigration officer gives me an exit stamp on the old passport and asks about my next destination, will it create any issues if I show my new passport when I mention that I am going to Malaysia?
At the same time, can I use my new passport when I arrive in Malaysia to obtain the visa on arrival? I will also use my new passport to book my tickets to Malaysia and to get the boarding pass, since my old passport has less than 6 months of validity and cannot be used for these purposes.
Will I encounter any issues by getting the exit stamp in the old passport and the entry stamp in the new passport when I arrive in Malaysia?
Will the Malaysian immigration officer require the exit stamp on the new passport?
I don't mind presenting both passports if the officer asks for them, but I want to ensure there won't be any problems having the exit stamp in one passport and the entry stamp in another.

I’m struggling to see any issues in this scenario. Exiting China you use your old passport (I’m not sure why you think they’d care where you go next, just that you leave on time). Entering Malaysia you have to use your new passport.

Are you sure your old passport is actually still valid? It may not be expired, but it may have been cancelled by the passport authorities of your countries when they issued the new one.

Please do not repost your question, certainly not in the fields for answers. The question has been seen, an answer will come when the right person sees it.

@jcaron It's not unheard of to get a second valid passport.  (See here for example).  But we don't have enough information from the OP to really know.

@PeterM indeed it isn’t (though rare, I believe), but this looks like a renewal rather than an application for a second passport. Note that I’m not saying the first passport was necessarily cancelled, just that it could be. Usually they retain or physically invalidate the old one, but anything is possible.

That's a bit of an unusual situation: typically your old passport is invalidated as soon as you receive a new one. There are of course exceptions, so it would help to understand, whether you really have an exception and what conditions (if any) are attached to it.
Assuming this is all fair and square and both passports are indeed valid, then:

Can I use my old passport to get the exit stamp from the immigration authorities in China since it has the visa and entry stamp from China?

Yes.

... asks about my next destination, will it create any issues if I show my new passport when I mention that I am going to Malaysia?

That's none of their business. They won't ask and there is no need to tell them. It's their job to manage exit from China. What happens after this is none of their concern.

can I use my new passport when I arrive in Malaysia to obtain the visa on arrival

Yes.

Will I encounter any issues by getting the exit stamp in the old passport and the entry stamp in the new passport when I arrive in Malaysia?

No. These are completely independent events and it's perfectly fine to switch passports between exit from A and entry into B. That's quite common for example for dual citizens.

Will the Malaysian immigration officer require the exit stamp on the new passport?

No. Similar rules apply. It's their job to manage entry into Malaysia. Your exit from the previous country is none of their concern.

I don't mind presenting both passports

There is no need to present both passports to anyone. Use the old passport when dealing with China, use the new one with Malaysia.

I will also use my new passport to book my tickets to Malaysia and to get the boarding pass,

It doesn't really matter much which passport you use when booking. However you MUST use the same passport during check in with the airline that you want to use to enter the destination country. It is probably a good idea to let the airline staff know that you are leaving China on a different passport. In some cases they may share the passenger manifest with the departure country as well.

While they shouldn’t care about passports for the other country, sometimes they are overzealous. The Chinese may want to check if you don’t have a passport from another country. The Malaysians may want to be sure you can leave (back to China, if that’s what the return ticket says) and thus have a valid visa. Or sometimes they’re just trying to be helpful as in “hey this expires soon are you sure you can enter the destination?”. But they shouldn’t have any issues with the situation.

First of all, I really appreciate your time and consideration. Here are the details regarding my passport situation:
Yes, both of my passports are valid.
I need some clarity here. I will use my new passport to book the tickets to Malaysia because it has more validity. As required for the visa on arrival, I need at least six months of validity in my passport. I cannot use my old passport as it has less than six months of validity left.
For the boarding pass, I will show my new passport to the airline since it is the one I used to book my ticket and it has the necessary validity.

this is the continuation for the above comments
The airline will not ask for my Chinese visa, but in case they do, I can present both passports.
As you mentioned, both the immigration authorities of China and Malaysia should not ask me for anything beyond my passport. However, if they do ask, it is fine to present both passports. This will not create any issues.
Again, thank you so much for your time and consideration. Please let me know if anything is unclear or if further explanation is needed.
Thank you.
